# SMB2FileId{persistentHandle=28 1e 03 b7 00 00 00 00}

Tags: java, spring, gradle, samba

I use a method that tries to get a list of files in a file directory through samba and count the number of them on the disk. The disk is 5 terabytes full. So the error comes out on the line diskShare.list(PATH) "com.hierynomus.smbj.common.SMBRuntimeException: com.hierynomus.protocol.transport.TransportException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hierynomus.smbj.common.SMBRuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout expired"

I use build.gradle  implementation 'com.hierynomus:smbj:0.12.2'.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class SambaServiceImpl implements SambaService {

@Value("${samba.servername}")
private String SERVERNAME;

@Value("${samba.username}")
private String USERNAME;

@Value("${samba.password}")
private String PASSWORD;

@Value("${samba.domain}")
private String DOMAIN;

@Value("${samba.share}")
private String SHARE;

@Value("${samba.path}")
private String PATH;

 public ResponseEntity<String> getConnectionTest() {
    try (SMBClient client = new SMBClient();) {
        AuthenticationContext auth = new AuthenticationContext(USERNAME, 
        PASSWORD.toCharArray(), DOMAIN);
        try (Session session = client.connect(SERVERNAME).authenticate(auth)) {

            try (DiskShare diskShare = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(SHARE)) {

                List<FileIdBothDirectoryInformation> files = diskShare.list(PATH);
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Size: " + files.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

}

I tried to increase the any timeout:

```
   try (SMBClient client = new SMBClient(SmbConfig.builder().withReadTimeout(1000000000, 
  TimeUnit.SECONDS).build())) {..}
```

but the error is the same.

please tell me how to be in such a situation? there are a lot of files on the disk and how to output everything?
I can choose one file by name, but that's not enough

```
        FileInformation file =
        diskShare.getFileInformation(PATH + "53039.pdf");
```